# Dll missing when installing VB6 application on Windows 10

Tags: windows, vb6, windows-10, windows-xp, 32bit-64bit

I have a very old VB6 application and I am using the Package and Development Wizard to make the setup file. The error occurred when I run the app:

[image]

I did some googling and I tried below solutions but none of them works:

- Checked the **adbapx.ocx** in System32 and SysWOW64, it is there.
- Registered **adbapx.ocx** manually by using regsvr32 cmd
- Run the **setup** file and **vb6** app file as administrator ( I did this every time)

Below is the **log file** during installation:

```
 %% PLEASE DO NOT MODIFY OR DELETE THIS FILE! %% 
 %% This file contains information about the installation of an application. %% 
 %% It will be used to automatically remove all application components from your computer if you choose to do so. %% 


NOTE: Beginning of the bootstrapper section

CONFIG: Title: "CCI Manager"

ACTION: RegKey: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion", "SharedDLLs"

ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VB6STKIT.DLL"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\COMCAT.DLL"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCRT40.DLL"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\STDOLE2.TLB"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ASYCFILT.DLL"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OLEPRO32.DLL"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OLEAUT32.DLL"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msvbvm60.dll"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\COMCAT.DLL"

ACTION: TLBRegister: "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\STDOLE2.TLB"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OLEPRO32.DLL"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OLEAUT32.DLL"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msvbvm60.dll"

NOTE: End of the bootstrapper section

NOTE: Now spawning the main Setup program 'Setup1.exe'....

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\RDOCURS.DLL"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\MSRDO20.DLL"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\SoftekBarcode.ocx"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\Code39draw.ocx"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\MSMAPI32.OCX"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\MSSTDFMT.DLL"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\MSADODC.OCX"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\MSINET.OCX"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\MSCOMCTL.OCX"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\Windows\System32\tdbgpp.dll"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\Windows\System32\todgub6.dll"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\todg6.ocx"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\adbapx.ocx"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\imgedit.ocx"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\comctl32.ocx"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\ImageMagickObject.dll"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\adbactvx.dll"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\MSBIND.DLL"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\Windows\System32\MSVCRT.DLL"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\scrrun.dll"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\Windows\System32\tibase6.dll"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\Windows\System32\tishare6.dll"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\titime6.ocx"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\tidate6.ocx"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\titext6.ocx"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Designer\MSDERUN.DLL"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\tinumbl6.ocx"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\VB5DB.DLL"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\Windows\System32\msrepl35.dll"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\Windows\System32\MSRD2X35.DLL"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\Windows\System32\expsrv.dll"
(File was not found or was an older version -- new file copied)

ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\Windows\System32\vbajet32.dll"
(File was not found or was an older version -- new file copied)

ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\Windows\System32\MSJINT35.DLL"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\Windows\System32\MSJTER35.DLL"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SystemFile: "C:\Windows\System32\msjet35.dll"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO\DAO350.DLL"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO\DAO2535.TLB"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\xarraydb.ocx"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\psapi.dll"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\wininet.dll"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\adbapi.dll"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)

ACTION: PrivateFile: "C:\Program Files (x86)\CCI Manager\CCI Manager.exe"
(File was not found or was an older version -- new file copied)

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\MSRDO20.DLL"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\SoftekBarcode.ocx"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\Code39draw.ocx"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\MSMAPI32.OCX"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\MSSTDFMT.DLL"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\MSADODC.OCX"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\MSINET.OCX"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\MSCOMCTL.OCX"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\todgub6.dll"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\todg6.ocx"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\adbapx.ocx"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\imgedit.ocx"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\comctl32.ocx"

*** ERROR: LoadLibrary() failed while registering file 'C:\Windows\System32\ImageMagickObject.dll'
*** DURING THIS ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\ImageMagickObject.dll"

*** ERROR: An error occurred while registering the file 'C:\Windows\System32\ImageMagickObject.dll'
*** ERROR: (User Responded with 'Ignore')
*** DURING THIS ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\ImageMagickObject.dll"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\adbactvx.dll"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\MSBIND.DLL"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\scrrun.dll"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\tishare6.dll"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\titime6.ocx"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\tidate6.ocx"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\titext6.ocx"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Designer\MSDERUN.DLL"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\tinumbl6.ocx"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\MSRD2X35.DLL"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\msjet35.dll"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO\DAO350.DLL"

ACTION: TLBRegister: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO\DAO2535.TLB"

ACTION: DllSelfRegister: "C:\Windows\System32\xarraydb.ocx"

ACTION: ShellLink: "CCI Manager", "CCI Manager"

ACTION: RegKey: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion", "App Paths\CCI Manager.exe"

ACTION: RegValue: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\CCI Manager.exe", ""
```

The imageMagick issue can be ignored. And to be noticed, this app was working really good on win10 during the last 3 months, but suddenly, the help desk told me the setup file is not working. I have this app installed already on my machine and I did another installation on my machine, the issue has been replicated. I tried open the app on user's PC without re-install, it is working.

It seems like the setup file caused the issue. I also tried the setup file on below system:

- Win7 32bit, same error but different file
- winXP 32bit, has another vb6 toolkit error during installation, but app runs without issue.

The interesting thing is that every time I try to make a setup package by using PDW, it says dll are missing. And I checked the references, they are there. And I also add these references again, but the PDW still shown the same warning.

Please help on this cause I really do not have these knowledge to solve the issue. Or may be other method I can try that I do not know, thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like the ocx was registered successfully by the installer.  So the key part of the message is `or one of its dependencies`.  You are likely missing a file on the target computer.  The challenge is to determine which file is missing.  [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) will help you determine which files the ocx requires, then you can manually try to see what is missing.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Really good point!! I am doing it now. I just noticed this too!!

Comment: You might want to try https://lucasg.github.io/Dependencies/ instead of Dependency Walker, apparently the latter has been left to fall out of date. Also if the static analysis these tools can do does not identify your missing dependency, try Process Monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the solutions are correct and worth to try. But I just solved my issue by using my solution.

Whenever our IT support team install the WIN10 to a new PC, the WIN10 install packaged they were using has the old version of dlls. But when I create setup package, the dlls I referenced are newer version. I copied the dlls that have newer version to the new PC (WIN10 PC). I listed below dlls I copied:

```
adbactvx.dll
adbapi.dll
adbapx.ocx
adbapxcc.dll
adbcom.dll
adbctls.ocx
```

I copied the above dll/ocx files to the SysWOW64 and replaced the old one. This solved my issue.

Comment: I was in a similar position. I have a bunch of different VB6 programs, which all use a core set of components. Some commercial ones and some written by me. My solution to that specific problem was to create a setup that just contains these shared components and provide it to our packaging team for inclusion into their rollout.

Answer (score 1):

*ACTION: SharedFile: "C:\Windows\System32\adbapx.ocx"
(File currently on disk was already up to date)*  As  Package and Development Wizard is 32 bit then when it says `"C:\Windows\System32\adbapx.ocx"` it means on 64 bit `"C:\Windows\Syswow64\adbapx.ocx"`. You need to register this one.

Answer (score 1):

There are two suggested ways to solve this issue.

**1 -** Try to open `cmd` as Administrator `sfc /scannow`this must do automatic repair for missing Dll files.

**2 -** Follow steps here [Register or Unregister ActiveX DLL or OCX Files](http://www.ctimls.com/Support/KB/How%20To/Register_dll.htm#Type%20regSvr32)